# can bzr show which files under the current directory has been added in the repository?

Tags: version-control, bazaar, bzr-svn

I know in cornerstone, the GUI will report which files are "added/deleted/conflict" from the repository. Does bzr have commands that could do similar things? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bzr status` command tells you the pending changes:

- files added
- files deleted
- files renamed
- unknown files (not yet added)

If you have installed the Bazaar Explorer plugin (included by default on Windows and Mac OS X) then you can also use Bazaar Explorer to show you the same information. On Windows you can open Bazaar Explorer from the Program Files or Start menu, on other systems you can run `bzr explorer /path/to/project`.